# Max length on a SAS of Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have been looking at Azure Storage Documentation but I could not find a way to limit the size of a blob when using a SAS. I can set the duration and the type of it but no the size. Do you know any way?

```
var sharedAccessPolicy = {
    AccessPolicy: {
        Permissions: azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
        Start: startDate,
        Expiry: expiryDate
    },
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: This is not the [tag:sas] you are looking for...

Answer (score 3):

Shared Access Signature (SAS) does not put any restriction on the blob size. If you create a SAS token with proper permission, user in possession of that SAS can upload a file of any size. You would need to handle this in your application.

What you can do is before the user start uploading the file using SAS, you check the size of the file and decline the request if the file size is more than allowed size.

Comment: Sad, this ends up relying on trusting client data. Wish the api was updated to support server side enforcement of blob size via SAS tokens, especially since the release of the javascript client lib.

Comment: We really need server-side validation. Users can use the token outside of the client app and upload files of any size. We cannot simply trust that file sizes will be within our criteria.